# How to create dictionary from different dataframes with different lenght and commun column?

Tags: python-2.7

I need to create a dictionary from 2 dataframes,

```
DF1 :
A              C       D        E
10.12.13.16   604    2345     4572
10.12.13.16   3300   3456     5664
10.24.35.14   200    9753     75498
10.24.35.14   360    9874     56789
10.24.35.14   740    4563     7643
10.24.35.14   634    0867     8754
16.22.27.11   212    7653     7543
16.22.27.11   786    2356     7644
16.22.27.11   345    9765     3467

DF2 : # is the len(A)
A             B
10.12.13.16   2
10.24.35.14   4
16.22.27.11   3
```

I need to create a dictionary, for each i in A, the lenght of A, C, D and E.
For example:

```
10.12.13.16 appear 2 times, with
     [C : 604, D: 2345, E : 4572] and [C : 3300, D : 3456, E : 5664]
10.24.35.14 appear 4 times, with
     [C : 200, D: 9753, E : 75498] and [C : 360, D : 9874, E : 56789] and 
     [C : 740, D: 4563, E : 7643] and [C : 634, D : 0867, E : 8754]
16.22.27.11 appear 3 times, with
     [C : 212, D : 7653, E : 7543] and [C : 786, D:2356, E : 7644] and
     [C : 345, D : 9765, E : 3467]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
unique_A = DF1.groupby("A").size().to_frame().rename(columns={0:'count'})

dictionary = { identifier: {"total_appearances": count['count'], "observations": [] } for identifier, count in unique_A.iterrows() }

for index, series in myFrame.iterrows():
    nested_dict = dictionary[series['A']]
    nested_dict["observations"].append(dict(series.iloc[1:]))
```

Comment: I updated to a different approach that should get you closer; although I do not know how performant it might end up being for larger and larger frames.

Comment: Thank you, I tried all the approachs that you suggest, but I coudn't get the result that I m looking for.

Comment: I made a few assumptions about what you would want to call the keys within each of the dictionaries associated with a unique 'A' value from DF1; but you can rename if you wish.  I also did away with the need for maintaining a DF2 since I am using a groupby operation on DF1 in conjunction with a dictionary comprehension to get the total count of each unique value in column A.

Comment: You are not being very clear about the output you are expecting.  The code I provided produces a dictionary with each unique entry in DF1 as a key that holds a nested dictionary carrying all the original information you asked for.  Are you getting errors?  Please provide a printout of what my code has produced in your editor.